# Range v3, side-effect view. Transform without transforming

Tags: c++, range-v3

I have a range and for every element I need to do something. But at the same time, I want to pass this range to another function that does its own job.

Thus traverse the range in two (or more) separate contexts, but still single pass.

I could do:

```
vector<int> speeds;

my_range = my_range | views::transform([&](auto&& element) {
    speeds.emplace_back(element.speed);
    return element;
});

auto sth = other_fn(my_range);
```

Is there something like `no_transform`, to indicate that actually I'm only adding a handler for the elements, and not *transforming* in the first place? (I would probably call it `for_each`, like in javascript, but I guess it's taken and does something else, right?)

usage:

```
vector<int> speeds;

my_range = my_range | views::no_transform([&](auto&& element) {
    speeds.emplace_back(element.speed);
});

auto sth = other_fn(my_range);

// another naming possibility
views::add_handler([&](auto&& element) {
```

---

(details about my other_fn:)

```
// other_fn builds adjacency list from sorted (from, to) edges, from, to are numeric ids
template <typename Element>
auto other_fn(ranges::any_view<Element> edges) {
    std::vector<size_t> adjacency_list;

    size_t i = 0;
    adjacency_list.emplace_back(0);

    auto last_from = (type of Element.from) -1;

    for (auto&& [from, to] : edges ) {
        if (from != last_from)
            adjacency_list.emplace_back(i);

        ++i;
    }

    adjacency_list.emplace_back(i);
    return adjacency_list;
}
```

Comment: Isn't `ranges::for_each(my_range, other_fn)` what you want?

Comment: @metalfox I think that's eager-evaluated. Thus I wouldn't be able reuse the input `my_range`.